# Release build fails with java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - React Native - Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

My android application throws the following error. The debug build works fine while the release build fails to run with the following error.

This is built with react native.

This error is logged through logcat.

```
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.enterprise, PID: 17107
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.enterprise/com.myapp.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001e type #0x1 is not valid
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001e type #0x1 is not valid
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2192)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1178)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:454)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow.setContentView(HwPhoneWindow.java:284)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:647)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:32)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6096)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:27)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:49)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:56)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
06-30 22:40:57.562 17107 17107 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
06-30 22:40:58.623 17127 17127 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Following is my MainActivity.java code.

```
package com.myapp;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myapp";
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where exactly the error is. And also the error is not clear enough for me. Please help me continue past this error. This is irritating.

I can post any additional content that is helpful for the question.

Comment: This appears to be related to the splash screen library that you're using. Make sure that you've set it up correctly and that whatever drawables you're passing it are valid

Comment: Thanks Kai. i found out the reason and added below/

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question here since I found out what happened.

It was not an issue from the android side. I was sweeping through the android code and gradle versions to make this right.

Finally I found out that this is an error thrown by the library, react-native-splash-screen. In their show() function, they have a bug that it fails to start when false is passed to the function.

Please refer this github issue. https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/167